# Why is favicon on bookmarks in Firefox different

Tags: reactjs, github, firefox, create-react-app, github-pages

I have published a website on GitHub Pages using React (with `npx create-react-app --template typescript`). Although I am able to change the favicon, I am unable to get the bookmarks favicon to change. I have tried using a different Firefox profile (namely, the Developer Edition as well) but still no luck. This behavior does not seem to exist in Chrome. How can I get the favicon in the bookmark toolbar to change as well?

Link to Github Repo: https://github.com/flyme2bluemoon/flyme2bluemoon.github.io/tree/gh-pages

Image:
[image]

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1230644

Comment: @RobbieDenton I have cleared my FF cache and added the shortcut icon but still the icon is the react logo.

Comment: A bit drastic, but you could always reinstall firefox.